# Why using onclick event in angular typescript must give it a void type?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, onclick, void

I am trying to call an onclick function in a typescript written in Angular, however, I don't know why this error shows up.

[image]

[image]

Does anyone know how to solve this type of issue? Please help and give me some suggestion, thanks in advance!

Comment: What do u want to do in code?

Comment: @Çağrı, morning sir, I would like to have an onclick event so that the web can be redirect to another page based on the same domain without reloading everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.onclick` expects a function and it seems you are assigning it to a result of a function call.

Try

```js
element.onclick = redirection;
```

Answer (score 1):

`element.onclick = redirection();` isn't what you want, is it? This means that you are setting an `onclick` event handler to the result of `redirection()` which happens to be undefined (since it's a void function)

I think you want to do this instead:

```
element.addEventListener('click', this.redirection.bind(this) );
```

Additionally, ***you shouldn't be applying events like this in Angular. It's a huge anti-pattern.*** Instead, find the element in your template and apply the click event the correct way

Example:

`<div (click)="redirection()">...</div>`

Or, even better yet, if `/ticketdashboard` is an angular route:

`<div routerLink="/ticketdashboard">...</div>`

Comment: Morning, lol I have to do it this way since I am not allowed to allocate my element given the fact that my button is generated through Microsoft botframework and the only attribute I got is its aria-label and class name. I cannot bind to it directly, but instead find the element and reassign an onclick event on it. Thanks a lot, I will try your code.

Comment: sorry man your method doesn't work...I tried another answer's suggestion it works fine. Thanks again for your time and care!